# How does time dilation apply at the centre of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, time-dilation

At the direct centre of a black hole, you have $0$ GPE, and the net gravitational force is $0$. So how does time dilation work there (or is this another physics mystery)?

Specification: I refer to how the time dilation changes from the actual surface of the black hole to the centre (I suspect it will continue to increase, but in a different way)

Related:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/251020/182917

Comment: There is no "actual surface" of a black hole.  There's an event horizon, but it is not a physical surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "center of a (Schwarzschild) black hole" in a traditional sense.  At the horizon, the schwarzschild "radial" direction switches from spacelike to timelike, and the singularity becomes more a "time in the future" than a "place you can go to".

Also, arguments like this about potential energy don't generalize well from Newtonian mechanics, and to the extent that you can use them, you have to use the relativistic generalizations of them, which involve terms that look like $1 - \frac{2M}{r}$, which is infinite for $r=0$